# woocommerce duplicate id and invalid customer id paytm

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders, paytm

We have a site on woocommerce with Paytm as payment gateway. We are facing an issue where in some orders are getting failed due to one following reasons.

1. Duplicate order id - Happens when customer tries to place an order which got failed earlier.
2. Invalid customer id - When customer id has space in first name.

Can any one help us with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by editing below file in WooCommerce Plugin.
File Name :  \public_html\wp-content\plugins\paytm\index.php

Before :

```
Line 389:            "CUST_ID" => $order -> billing_first_name,
Line 478:            $paytm_args_array[] = "<input type='hidden' name='CUST_ID' value='". $order -> billing_first_name ."'/>";
```

After :

```
Line 389:            "CUST_ID" => $email,
Line 478:            $paytm_args_array[] = "<input type='hidden' name='CUST_ID' value='". $email ."'/>";
```